# google console can't find my already defined variable

Tags: javascript

This is the content inside draw.js file and the error seems to be related with line 11 and 13

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const scale = 10;
const rows = canvas.height / scale;
const columns = canvas.width / scale;

console.log("hello world")
var snake;

(function setup() {
  snake = new Snake();
  snake.draw();
}())
```

snake.js file content

```
function snake() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, scale, scale);
  }
}
```

Comment: What variable are you referring to? And how are you trying to access it?

Comment: What are the errors? Based on this I assume that however you're including `snake.js` doesn't have access to `ctx`.

Comment: I accessed the files in a html file, which isn't shown here, but it's accessed because console.log("Hello world") works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is declared as

```
snake(){ ... }
```

You should declare as

```
Snake(){ ... }
```

---

Full example ( I tested, it works! fillStyle was changed to black. )

```
<html>

<body>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        function Snake() {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;

            this.draw = function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, scale, scale);
            }
        }
        const canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const scale = 10;
        const rows = canvas.height / scale;
        const columns = canvas.width / scale;

        console.log("hello world")
        var snake;

        (function setup() {
            snake = new Snake();
            snake.draw();
        }())
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried to edit snake to Snake in the snake.js file, but it didn't help

Comment: I edited the response with a full code. Have fun :D